# RDP ActiveX Client IMsRdpExtendedSettings Variant types?

Tags: winapi, com, activex, rdp

Looking at [Supported RDP properties with Remote Desktop Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/rdp-files) to find properties to set but it doesn't tell you what `VARIANT` type they are using.  Is it `VT_BOOL` and 0, -1 vs 0, 1 or `VT_I2` or `VT_I4`, or several of the other types available dealing with integers / numbers?

Comment: Just VT_I4 and VT_BSTR.  Doesn't actually matter that much, it will use VariantChangeType to coerce the passed value to the type it expects.